# Created UILabel programmatically with constraints. Now i want to update the height constraints of the UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, constraints, uilabel

My code is as below

`movieDescLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 movieDescLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 87).isActive = true`

I am not sure how to update the height constraints programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a var

```
var heightCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Assign

```
heightCon = movieDescLbl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 87)
heightCon.isActive = true
```

Update

```
heightCon.constant = 200
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

OR

```
heightCon.isActive = true/false
```